# Regex Match text between 2 Character

Tags: java, regex

I have this kind of line :

```
#RT_POOL_CELL1_1 : RT_CELL_T :=  (NEXT     => 0,

#RT_IS_OK                   : BOOLEAN := TRUE;
#RT_RESULT_UPDATE_TM_INFO.TC_INFO : PUS.TYPES.RESULT_UPDATE_TM_INFO_T := PUS.TYPES.UPDATE_OK;
```

And I need to take RT_POOL_CELL1_1, RT_IS_OK and RT_RESULT_UPDATE_TM_INFO (without the dot .TC_INFO) in java with regex.

I tried to make that with this regex : 
\s*[#][[:ascii:]]\s*[:|.]

But it doen't work. The thing to know is the word I need to take is always between # and :, they can contains space between word et sign. And if there is a ., I juste take the word before the dot.

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex based on lookarounds:

```
(?<=#)[^:.]+?(?= *[:.])
```

**Breakup of regex:**

```
(?<=#)     # makes sure there is preceding #
[^:.]+?    # match anything but : or . (non-greedy)
(?= *[:.]) # makes sure this is followed by 0 or more spaces and : or .
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vX5hZ3/2)

Answer (score 1):

To match the word:

```
(?<=#)[^: .]+(?=.*:)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/PpNwkj7DRi).